# Nvidia Driver outdated, will the PPA help? And what's a PPA?

Tags: nvidia, ppa, packaging

Hi I'm a complete novice (usually rely on my son for help). In one of the answers it mentions 'ppa'. What is 'ppa'?

If this problem is resolved will it stop the freezing as well?

Comment: Rat2000's answer does you for what a PPA is and which one you'd probably want to use... But I can't tell you if it's the right decision. The x-updates PPA generally has newer software in it which can be both a good and a bad thing. They're [fairly easy to remove and revert though](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them/91660#91660) so it might be worth a test.

Answer (score 1):

> Personal Package Archives (PPA) allow you to upload Ubuntu source
>   packages to be built and published as an apt repository by Launchpad.
>   You can find out more about PPAs and how to use them in our help page.

In other words PPA's are maintained by the community and for the user it is more simple to install from a PPA and to keep it updated then it would be to do all the packaging and installing himself.

Now if you want to have stable Nvidia drivers you should:

Press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (to open a terminal) and run this commands one by one:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I have type `dist-upgrade` since you said you already have the Nvidia driver installed, if you don't instead of the last command just type:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```